# Timepicker behaving differently

Tags: javascript, jquery

On [Trent's website](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#basic_examples), the simple usage of Timepicker is given as:

```
$('#basic_example_2').timepicker();
```

The result is as below:

[image: result of basic_example_2]

Few examples later, there is an example of timepicker with grid.

```
$('#slider_example_1').timepicker({
    hourGrid: 4,
    minuteGrid: 10,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
```

The result is as below:

[image: slider_example_1]

When I use the same code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9xc7/77/), I am getting different results.

How do I make the Fiddle behave as the examples on Trent's website? I do not want seconds, millisecond, microsecond and timezone. Can someone please help with this. I am new to javascript.

Comment: have you added js files  to jsfiddle?

Comment: @DharaParmar: I have. That's why am getting the result! right ?